# get_post_type() function does not return anything

Tags: wordpress

I want to `get_post_type` of current post.

If I try `get_post_type()`, it does not return anything.

I tried `get_post_type(124)` and it works. 124 is the current post_id.

In my function.php of child theme

```
<?php
global $post;
$my_post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
?>
```

Can anybody tell me how to make `get_post_type()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (needs to be inside the loop)

```
get_post_type( get_the_ID() )
```

Outside the loop:

```
global $post;
get_post_type($post->ID)
```

Comment: I dont put inside the loop. I just put them in function.php of the child theme.

Comment: i got error : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\ma-child\functions.php on line 92

Comment: Please post your whole code snippet so I can see what the issue could be.

Comment: <?php
global $post;
$my_post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
?>

Comment: Is that your whole code for functions.php? It should be added to a hook or filter...

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: CAVEAT: The $post global will ONLY have been set "outside the loop" if either 1) you set it yourself OR 2) You have called WP_Query to set up "the loop" followed by a call to WP_Query::the_post() which initializes $post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish this within a loop? If so you could try:

```
$current_post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
echo $current_post_type;
```

Comment: I dont put inside the loop. I just put them in function.php of the child theme.